# XLViewer not working for XLSX attachments

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have users who want to open Excel attachments from a list item but sharepoint insists that it opens using xlviewer but it never works. There is always an error that says try again in a few minutes.

I just want to allow them to download it or to open it directly with excel or the associated application.

Comment: Is Excel Services up and running in Central Administration?

Comment: Excel Calculation Service is started and running. I dont see any other Excel services

Comment: I do see Excel Services Application and it is also running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're the site collection admin. Go into the site (not the central admin) and then go to site settings then go to site collection features. In there you will find the setting for " Open Documents in Client Applications by Default " it will probably be deactivated. Active it and you're good to go. users will then open attachments in their windows assigned applications, not the sharepoint web apps.